# Quantum Eraser Mars Communicator and Alien Detector!

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-eraser

Build a Quantum Eraser Mars Communicator (QEMC) with one detector E on Earth and another detector M on Mars. The detector M also has an eraser QE which can be turned on or off by Elon Musk on Mars. The QEMC sends splits one second pulses of beams between the two detectors. By turning QE on or off in Mars, Elon is able to create interference patterns on E as per his will. Using this he will be able to communicate with Earth by earthlings reading out the sequence of interference patterns on the one second pulse beams over time.

The thing to note is that this will NOT be faster than light communication, because the pulse beams will travel to Mars only at the speed of light and take 4 minutes to do so, only after which can Elon turn the switch on/off. However the interference pattern on E will be observed for an event that will occur on Mars 4 minutes later from this point, when Elon presses the on/off switch for the eraser. So it is possible to communicate with the future but not at faster than light speeds.

Similarly, if some alien civilization is scanning the sky for laser beams, with an M type detector, even if it is one million light years away, if it can get the pulse beam from E, it will be able to turn its QE on or off just like Elon and be able to communicate with earth of the past.

What do you think? Is this feasible??

Comment: the interference patterns are actually timing correlations between E and M detectors, hence they are undetectable without comparing both arrival timestamps (which must travel to a common station via regular light signals)

Comment: arrival timestamps can be encoded into the beam by changing the pulse duration for example

Comment: So you send a message encoded in the pattern correlations in the beam, which you need arrival timestamps to decode. So then you send the arrival timestamps with the beam, which you need arrival timestamps to decode. So then you send the arrival timestamps of the arrival timestamp message, which you... and then you give up and use an ordinary radio signal. Elon wouldn't waste his time with this.

Comment: you got it wrong. message is not encoded in the pattern correlations in the beam. the start time is encoded in the pulse duration.. the rest of it is calculated based on the time taken by the signal to travel the distance.. in any case, the entire pulse is just one bit so the sequence of bits will give you the message.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in this, so I looked up the experiment in [wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment)

[image: quantum eraser]

> This experiment involves an apparatus with two main sections. After two entangled photons are created, each is directed into its own section of the apparatus. Anything done to learn the path of the entangled partner of the photon being examined in the double-slit part of the apparatus will influence the second photon, and vice versa.

I think with this description , one way communication on earth  is possible. One would need a symmetric setup for responses. But we have no problem communicating within  earth.   Now lasers to Mars make me dubious, considering that the laser beams do open up. Look what happens with the [Apollo reflector in the moon,](https://www.space.com/apollo-retroreflector-experiment-still-going-50-years-later.html)

Comment: the widening is more of a reflector problem.. should be possible to send sharp laser beams to Mars. the alien detector is where it gets curiouser! :p

Comment: The alien would have to set up a double slit , it would have to guess that the beam  is entangled , a very very  small probability ( also considering dispersion)

Comment: True, but it may just build a setup just for heck

Comment: @Smagula: laser beams inherently widen, even if very sharp and parallel at emission. No amount of engineering can get you through the diffraction limit. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_divergence for example. You would need a very very wide beam to have small divergence. This is only a comment, and it's Friday night ;), so I did not do the calculation, but my gut instinct is that you would need a very very wide beam to have it extend by only a small factor, say 10, up to Mars.

Comment: https://www.insidescience.org/news/how-far-can-laser-light-travel -- for light reference